# Rust type mismatch resolving `for<'r> ...` with closure trait alias argument

Tags: rust, closures, traits, lifetime

Trait aliases aren't in stable Rust right now, but I tried to emulate them (giving a nicer name to a particular kind of closure) by doing

```rust
trait MyCallback: FnMut(&u32) -> () { }

impl<F: FnMut(&u32) -> ()> MyCallback for F { }
```

which has worked great for other kinds of trait aliases I've needed. But then when I tried to use the trait alias, I had lifetime problems(?) which I couldn't resolve. Consider the following two duplicate functions, just with `MyCallback` replaced with its "definition" in the second case.

```rust
fn process_data(mut f: impl MyCallback) -> () {
    f(&0)
}

fn process_data_2(mut f: impl FnMut(&u32) -> ()) -> () {
    f(&0)
}

fn main() {
    // Doesn't compile
    process_data(|_| ());

    // Compiles
    process_data_2(|_| ());
}
```

(Complete example on the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7c490716445faac1ef228ccdd74ed417).)
As commented, the function using the alias won't accept the argument I want to pass it. I would guess that I need to manually insert some lifetimes in the trait definition to emulate what the compiler is implicitly doing as it parses `process_data_2`, but I can't figure out how to proceed (my attempts to insert `for<'a>` clauses, which I just learnt about, all failed).

How can I make my code compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it compile, you can add a type annotation to your closure:

```
process_data(|_: &u32| ());
```

This seems to be related to [this longstanding issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37464).

Comment: Thanks. Also linked in that issue was [this one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35714), where it is stated that (a very related issue) is unfixable due to the current typechecker design.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post, you are trying to use the trait to create a "callback" type.  If that *is* indeed the case, you're better off using a function alias, like this:

```
pub type MyCallback = fn(&u32) -> ();

fn process_data(mut f: MyCallback) -> () {
    f(&0)
}
```

The error message you're getting is due to the issue that nnnmmm posted above... right as I was typing this post :p

Comment: The problem is that I'd like `f: MyCallback` to have internal mutable state and get called many times, and I ripped this out to make an MRE. Thanks for your help though!